# VB.NET: SelectedIndexChanged firing multiple times

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling, controls, selectedindexchanged

I am trying to programmatically add an unspecified amount of new UserControls to a form. One will be added every time an entry is selected in a ComboBox contained within the UserControl.

Problem is, the SelectedIndexChanged event fires completely erratically. Sometimes twice, sometimes 3 times, etc., but never just once. No matter how many times I set the combobox's SelectedIndex to -1, it fires at least once with a SelectedIndex of 0. Sometimes the Itemselected event fires multiple times inbetween SelectedIndexChanged events.

InvoiceEntry.vb snippet:

```
Public Event ItemSelected As EventHandler
Private Sub cboItem_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, _
            e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboItem.SelectedIndexChanged
    RaiseEvent ItemSelected(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

Invoice.vb snippet:

```
Private numEntries As Integer = 1

Public Sub invEntry1_ItemSelected() Handles invEntry1.ItemSelected
    numEntries += 1

    Dim newEntry As InvoiceEntry = invEntry1
    Dim pt As Point = newEntry.Location
    pt.Y += 30

    newEntry.Location = pt
    newEntry.Name = "invEntry" + numEntries.ToString

    pnlEntries.Controls.Add(newEntry)
```

End Sub

I'm at a complete loss as to what is wrong. Please let me know if you need more information, as I will be monitoring this thread until I or someone else figures it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, when you add new combo box the selected index is changing at this time (this is when it triggers first time). It will also trigger every time you programatically change a value.

If you want to generate controls after user has selected something from the combo box try using

```
ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx

Comment: That is *exactly* what I was looking for! This problem has haunted me so many times in the past, and I've never been able to find an appropriate solution. You, sir, are a hero.

Answer (score 0):

with listview i had same problem.
i used this:

```
if (listview.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
   //do something...
}
```