# How to prevent multiple SelectedIndexChanged events from being thrown?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a combobox in winforms, which, depending on what you select, determines what's populated in other comboboxes. I filled the initial combobox using a dataview:

```
combobox_process.DataSource = dataview
combobox_process.DisplayMember = "UserDefine1"
combobox_process.SelectedIndex = -1
```

Which works fine, except every one of those lines throws the SelectedIndexChanged event. The function that populates the next combobox listens for that event and so it's running three times. I asked a coworker and he suggested just looping through the data and adding them all manually as strings, but I'd prefer to stick with databinding if I can. Especially if, in the future, I need to do something that I can only do with databinding.

Any thoughts? Perhaps some way to disable that event during a portion of this code?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for - `ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted`::http://stackoverflow.com/a/10333311/763026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just unbind your event handler before you make the call and then rebind it when the call is done.

Answer (score 3):

Events firing when you not want them to is a common problem in Windows Forms - SelectedIndexChanged is a typical example. One approach I often use is to declare a flag that is set when running a portion of code that I know will fire the event when I'm not interested in listening to it.

An example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private m_IsSettingDataSource As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Me.m_IsSettingDataSource = True
            combobox_process.DataSource = DataView
            combobox_process.DisplayMember = "UserDefine1"
            combobox_process.SelectedIndex = -1
        Catch
            Throw
        Finally
            Me.m_IsSettingDataSource = False
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub combobox_process_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles combobox_process.SelectedIndexChanged
        If Not Me.m_IsSettingDataSource Then
            ' Do what you want to do when not setting data source
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can either do this, or like John said, turn off and on the event handler. The flag approach may be better when you know that two or more event handlers will be affected.